# How to optimize multithreaded program for use in LSF?

Tags: multithreading, ipc, job-scheduling, lsf

I am working on a multithreaded number crunching app, let's call it `myprogram`. I plan to run `myprogram` on IBM's LSF grid. LSF allows a job to scheduled on CPUs from different machines. For example, `bsub -n 3 ... myprogram ...` can allocate two CPUs from node1 and one CPU from node2.

I know that I can ask LSF to allocate all 3 cores in the same node, but I am interested in the case where my job is scheduled onto different nodes.

1. How does LSF manage this? Will `myprogram` be run in two different processes in node1 and node2?
2. Does LSF automatically manage data transfer between node1 and node2?
3. Anything I can do in `myprogram` to make this easy for LSF to manage? Should I be making use of any LSF libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to Q1**

When you submit a job like `bsub -n 3 myprogram`, all LSF does is allocate 3 slots across 1-3 hosts.  One of these hosts will be designated as the "first execution host", and LSF will dispatch and run a single instance of `myprogram` on that host.

If you want to run `myprogram` in parallel, LSF has a command called `blaunch` which will essentially launch one instance of a program per allocated core.  For example, submit your job like `bsub -n 3 blaunch myprogram` will run 3 instances of `myprogram`.

**Answer to Q2**

By "manage data transfer" I assume you mean communication between the instances of `myprogram`.  The answer is no, LSF is a scheduling and dispatching tool.  All it does is allocation and dispatch, but it has no knowledge of what the dispatched program is doing.  `blaunch` in turn is simply a task launcher, it just launches multiple instances of a task.

What you're after here is some kind of parallel programming framework like MPI (see for example www.openmpi.org).  This provides a set of APIs and commands that allow you to write `myprogram` in a parallel fashion.

Once you've done that and turned your program in to `mympiprogram`, you can submit it to LSF like `bsub -n 3 mpirun mympiprogram`.  The `mpirun` tool - at least in the case of OpenMPI (and some others) - integrates with LSF, and uses the `blaunch` interface under the hood to launch your tasks for you.

**Answer to Q3**

You don't need to use LSF libraries in your program to make anything easier for LSF, like I said what's going on inside the program is transparent to the system.  LSF libraries just enable your program to become a client of the LSF system (submit jobs, query, etc...)

Comment: Thanks. Openmpi looks interesting.